# terminal can't find enchant while running ./configure

Tags: editor, configure, subtitle

I'm working on Ubuntu Studio 14.04, and I'm trying to upgrade Subtitle Editor, whose version in the repositories is 0.41.0, even though, as I see [here](http://home.gna.org/subtitleeditor/), version 0.51.0 is out since April.

So, I downloaded it, and while running ./configure I run in this error:

```
[...]
checking for ENCHANT... no
configure: error: Package requirements (enchant >= 1.4.0) were not met:

No package 'enchant' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ENCHANT_CFLAGS
and ENCHANT_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

The issue is that enchant is actually already installed, in a version >=1.4.0:

```
alex@Sargon:~/Scaricati/subtitleeditor-0.51.0$ enchant -v
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Enchant 1.6.0)
```

Running `pkg-config enchant` doesn't solve the problem.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Did you try installing the development components for enchant? `sudo apt-get install libenchant-dev`.

Comment: I didn't, and that solved the problem.

Comment: If you write it in an answer I check it as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing the development components for enchant. `sudo apt-get install libenchant-dev`. This is usually needed when building software from source: the package (`enchant`) contains the binaries and runtime libraries, but usually the headers needed to build software that depends on that particular library are split off into a `-dev` package.